# How to dispatch form-submission-style ajax requests when using Hooks / Effects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to understand where to properly dispatch ajax `fetch` requests in response to things like a button click or form submission, when using hooks and effects? Am I allowed to submit an http request in a button click handler, or do I have to rig up some effect-driven way of doing this?

For example, can I just do something like ...

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = React.useState();

  async function MakeRequest() {
    const res = await fetch( ... );
    setFoo(res);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => MakeRequest()}>
      {res}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes. As outlined in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), you can define the hook like this:

```
<button onClick={activateLasers}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

This also means you can pass an anonymous function, e.g.:

```
<button onClick={() => { activateLasers() }}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

The hook function can be synchronous or asynchronous. If it is asynchronous, then a recommended approach would be to update the state when the call finishes, that way the DOM is re-rendered with the new information asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid strategy. Just remember that if you want to use the returned values to use setState and not just define a variable.

this would work.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();
  async function makeRequest() {
    await fetch( ... );
    setRespone(/*...*/);
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={makeRequest} />
  )
}
```

while this wouldn't work

```
function MyComponent() {
  let response;
  async function makeRequest() {
    await fetch( ... );
    response = /*...*/;
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={makeRequest} />
  )
}
```